# Zsh find permission denied - Application Saved State

Tags: bash, permissions, find, zsh

Whenever I use the find command in zsh, if I have it run from the user level, it always outputs a specific permission denied message (in addition to any found paths) For example:

```
$ find "/Users/usr" -name "Python.gitignore"

/Users/usr/Dropbox/Programming/Git/gitignore/Python.gitignore
find: /Users/usr/Library/Saved Application State/com.bitrock.appinstaller.savedState: Permission denied
```

But if it's run on any subdirectory of `/Users/usr` (except `Users/usr/Library`) it works as expected:

```
$ find "/Users/usr/Dropbox" -name "Python.gitignore"

/Users/vivekjha/Dropbox/Programming/Git/gitignore/Python.gitignore
```

What is a "Saved Application State" and how can I prevent this error message from outputting when running `find`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to hide all the permission error messages from the find command, you can directly redirect its stderr to /dev/null

```
find "/Users/usr" -name "Python.gitignore" 2> /dev/null;
```

However you might hide other error messages that what you want, therefore you could filter it out in the following way:

```
 find "/Users/usr" -name "Python.gitignore" 2>&1 | grep -v ": Permission denied$"
```

Answer (score 0):

And alternative to *find* would be to use zsh globbing. The following will most likely return the results you want.

```
$ print -l /Users/usr/**/Python.gitignore(N)
```